# controlar minimizar y maximizar con el icono de la barra de tareas ventana Fija

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una ventana fija sin bordes, a la que le elimine los botones de maximiza y minimizar, etc, que cubre completamente la pantalla del usuario, pero deja visible la barra de tarea de la siguiente forma:

```
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
Left = Top = 0;
Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
ShowInTaskbar = true;
```

pero al no tener los botones de maximizar y minimizar no permite minimizar la ventana y se siente antinatural la navegación entre programas abiertos o buscar algo en el escritorio...

he intentado replicar el evento de minimizar y maximizar capturando el evento con el activate de la siguiente forma:

```
public void Toggle_Windows(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized | this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        ShowInTaskbar = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
```

pero no funciona correctamente ya que me oculta la ventana y me oculta el icono en la barra de tarea.
no tengo ningún mensaje o error del depurador de código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De forma predeterminada, los formularios sin bordes no están diseñados para minimizarse, lo que significa que cuando la propiedad `FormBorderStyle` del formulario se establece en `none`, observará que hacer clic en el cuadro de la aplicación en la barra de tareas no minimiza el formulario.

Esto se puede solucionar anulando `CreateParams` y agregando el estilo `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` a la ventana y `CS_DBLCLKS` a los estilos de clase de la ventana.

Simplemente agregando el siguiente codigo se obtiene el minimizadoi de la ventana:

```
const int WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000;
const int CS_DBLCLKS = 0x8;
 
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.Style |= WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
        cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DBLCLKS;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Fuente:

https://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/minimize-a-form-without-border-using-the-taskbar/

Answer (score 1):

A mi me sucedió eso y lo resolví de la siguiente manera, hice que la aplicación que quedara minimizada al dar doble click en el formulario.

Para ello ponemos este código en el **evento DoubleClick** del formulario:

```
if(((MouseEventArgs)e).Button == MouseButtons.Left)
{
   this.WinfowsState = FormWinfowsState.Minimized;
}
```

De esta forma preguntamos si el botón del mouse que se apretó es el izquierdo, de cumplirse esta condición la aplicación quedará minimizada al dar doble click en cualquier lugar del formulario.

Comment: mi escenario es un poco distinto, el form esta cubierto por un elemento cefsharp que abre una pagina web, estoy usando el click derecho para mostrar un menu contextual. lo unico que se me ocurre es si se puede capturar el click del icono de la barra de tarea...

Comment: lo que busco seria que únicamente con dar click en el icono, pueda hacer Toggle a minimizar y maximizar

Comment: Si ya veo, en el caso mío el formulario estaba limpio, te sigo la publicación

Comment: o mejor dicho la pregunta puede ser: que hace que un programa se abra y cierre al hacerle click en el icono de la barra de tareas, y por que no funciona en una ventana borderless

Comment: ya resolví el problema pero ahora no tiene el efecto de desvanecimiento...